# Custom checkbox - disabled state color

Tags: vb.net, checkbox, controls

I have a custom checkbox witch allows resizing of the main rectangle. But when I want to set it as disabled, it doesnt gray out like normal checkbox control does. It just stays white.

Here is class for custom checkbox to allow resizing:

```
Public Class NewCheckBox
Inherits CheckBox

Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(ByVal e As PaintEventArgs)
    MyBase.OnPaint(e)

    'Make the box you check 3/4 the height
    Dim boxsize As Integer = Me.Height * 0.75
    Dim rect As New Rectangle(
        New Point(0, Me.Height / 2 - boxsize / 2),
        New Size(boxsize, boxsize)
    )
    ControlPaint.DrawCheckBox(e.Graphics, rect, If(Me.Checked, ButtonState.Checked, ButtonState.Normal))
End Sub 
End Class
```

Here is how i want to use it:

```
Private Sub txtFpo_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtFpo.TextChanged

    If functii.verificaLaser(txtFpo.Text) = True Then
        NewCheckBox1.Enabled = False
        'NewCheckBox1.ForeColor = Color.DarkGray
    End If
```

I've tried to set the forecolor property, but to no avail.

How can i make the custom control to be greyed out in disabled mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anything in your code that specifies how to paint based on whether the control is disabled or not, so of course it doesn't change.  `Inactive` is one of the `ButtonState` values so you need to specify that when the control is disabled.

```
Dim buttonState = ButtonState.Normal

If Me.Checked Then
    buttonState = buttonState Or ButtonState.Checked
End If

If Not Me.Enabled Then
    buttonState = buttonState Or ButtonState.Inactive
End If

ControlPaint.DrawCheckBox(e.Graphics, rect, buttonState)
```